# Fabric.js group/ungroup - individual objects disappear while ungrouping

Tags: angularjs, fabricjs

I have this functions in my angularJS controller:

```
    function group(){
    var activegroup = canvas.getActiveGroup();
    var objectsInGroup = activegroup.getObjects();

    activegroup.clone(function(newgroup) {
        canvas.discardActiveGroup();
        objectsInGroup.forEach(function(object) {
            canvas.remove(object);  
        });
        canvas.add(newgroup);

    });
}

function ungroup(){
   var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if(activeObject.type=="group"){
        var items = activeObject._objects;
        activeObject._restoreObjectsState();
        canvas.remove(activeObject);
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          canvas.add(items[i]);
          canvas.item(canvas.size()-1).hasControls = true;
        }
    }
        canvas.renderAll();
}
```

Working almost perfectly - jus when I ungroup the objects are not rendered (they are still in the canvas, but not visible). I can select the objects individually even if they are invisible. Selectin multiple object will show them while they are selected – deselecting one will let the other disappear. In short: ungrouping objects will not show as individual objects again.

This applys only to primitives like, box, circle, triangle. Text an images are not affected.

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ungroup(){
 var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
if(activeObject.type=="group"){
    var items = activeObject._objects;
    alert(items);
    activeObject._restoreObjectsState();
    canvas.remove(activeObject);
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      canvas.add(items[i]);
      items[i].dirty = true; //set object dirty true
      canvas.item(canvas.size()-1).hasControls = true;
    }

    canvas.renderAll();
 }
}
```

If you set object dirty true, it will render in renderAll() call and redraw again.

Comment: Thanks mate! Working really like a charme!

Comment: my fail as a novice stackoverflow user (well novice ebverything I guess). I found the way to mark the question as solved :-)